# Singleton does not return any image

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

i'm trying to fetch the profile image from FB and save it using a singleton class, but it does not seem to save any image when i try to show it in a UIImageView. i've tested the code where the facebook profile image is beeing fetched and it works. why ain't it not working using singleton?

## FBSingleton.h

```
@implementation FBSingleton

static FBSingleton *sharedInstance = nil;

// Get the shared instance and create it if necessary.
+ (FBSingleton *)sharedInstance {
    if (sharedInstance == nil) {
        sharedInstance = [[super allocWithZone:NULL] init];
    }

    return sharedInstance;
}


- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        // Work your initialising magic here as you normally would

        self.userImage = [[UIImage alloc] init];
    }

    return self;
}

@end
```

## FBSingleton.h

```
@interface FBSingleton : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImage *userImage;

+ (instancetype)sharedInstance;
@end
```

## ViewController.h - saving the UIImage

```
    UIImage *theImage = [[FBSingleton sharedInstance] userImage];

    if (!theImage) {
        // download the image from Facebook and then save it into the singleton



        [FBRequestConnection
         startForMeWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
             if (!error) {
                 NSString *facebookId = [result objectForKey:@"id"];

             FBSingleton *sharedSingleton = [FBSingleton sharedInstance];

                UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture?type=large", facebookId ]]]];

                 sharedSingleton.userImage = image;

             }
         }];




    }
```

## AnotherViewController.m - fetching form singleton class

```
FBSingleton *sharedSingleton = [FBSingleton sharedInstance];
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(tableView.frame.size.width/2-75, 50.0f, 100.0f, 100.0f)];
    [imageView setImage:sharedSingleton.userImage];

    [self.view addSubview:imageView];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you missed `@synchronized(self)` in singleton  class init

```
FBSingleton *sharedInstance = nil;

// Get the shared instance and create it if necessary.

    + (FBSingleton *)sharedInstance {
        @synchronized(self){
            if (sharedInstance == nil) {
                sharedInstance = [[super allocWithZone:NULL] init];
            }
        }
        return sharedInstance;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, when you call `[FBSingleton sharedInstance]` then `init` method of `FBSingleton` class will not called, because in `+sharedInstance` you called `[super allocWithZone]` instead of `[self new];` I.e. the final version must be like this:

```
+ (instancetype)sharedInstance
{
    static id instance = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        instance = [self new]; //or [[self alloc] init] which is the same
    });

    return instance;
}
```